# What's the problem of pause() at all?

Tags: signals

According to [this paragraph](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Pause-Problems.html#Pause-Problems) ,the following has problem:

```
 /* usr_interrupt is set by the signal handler.  */
 if (!usr_interrupt)
   pause ();
 
 /* Do work once the signal arrives.  */
 ...
```

And should use [`sigsuspend`](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Sigsuspend.html#Sigsuspend) instead.

But I still don't see what the problem is with `pause` and how `sigsuspend` solves it,

anyone can explain in more details?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's examine what happens when a signal arrives after you've checked `usr_interrupt` but *before* you call `pause`:

```
main thread                            signal handler
-----------                            --------------
if (!usr_interrupt)
// this is true                        // signal kicks up handler
                                       usr_interrupt = 1;
                                       // handler finishes
pause();
// will wait for signal
```

You can see in that case that you've *missed* the signal. Extremely important if there is no further signal incoming since your program will *never* action it. That's what's known as a race condition. Now let's see what happens with `sigsuspend`:

```
main thread                            signal handler
-----------                            --------------
// set up to delay signal.
sigemptyset (&mask);
sigaddset (&mask, SIGUSR1);

// this will delay (block) signal.
// possibly do this first if USR1
//   may be blocked already (check!):
//   sigprocmask (SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, &old);
sigprocmask (SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &old);

if (!usr_interrupt)
                                       // signal arrives, delayed.
// unblock signal/wait (atomically).
sigsuspend (&old);
                                       // delayed handler start.
                                       usr_interrupt = 1;
                                       // handler finishes.
// sigsuspend returns, clean up.
sigprocmask (SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, NULL);
```

In this case, there is no race condition since the signal is delayed until the main thread is ready for it.

Comment: What if the signal is also blocked in `old`?

Comment: @wireshark: if you set it up incorrectly then it won't work. But that's true of everything so I'm not sure what your point is. If you want to ensure it's set up properly, just unblock USR1 first.

Comment: do you know gdb's internal signal handling? Hopefully you know the answer for my previous question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301130/sigint-not-trapped-while-debugging-nginx-with-gdb

Comment: Also,what's the difference between sigsuspend and sigwait?

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic race condition.

```
Main                | Signal handler
--------------------|-----------------------
// at this point,   |
// no signal has    |
// arrived, so we   |
// enter the if     |
                    |
if (!usr_interrupt) | 
                    | {signal arrives...}
                    | usr_interrupt = 1;
                    | {...handler finishes}
pause();            |
                    |
// uh-oh, we missed |
// the signal!      |
```

Now the `pause()` won't get unblocked until the *next* signal arrives (which may never happen depending on the program).