# Make something on received signal

Tags: c

I'm trying to run something in the same function I'm in when I receive a signal from another process. I can't figure out how to do anything except execute in another function... Here is the code I tried:

```
void connected(int signum)
{
    write(1, "\nenemy connected\n\n", 18);
}

void connect_parent(void)
{
    char ** map;
    write(1, "my_pid: ", 9);
    my_putnbr(getpid());
    write(1, "\nwaiting for enemy connection...\n", 34);
    if (signal(SIGCONT, connected))
        map = host_map();
    for (int i = 1;;i++);
}
```

After testing my code, I realize that my yew is not good. Is there a solution to make this kind of thing work?

Comment: "Yew"? Your last `for` loop will use 100% CPU, which might lead your system to some interesting problems. Use a static semaphore instead, wait on it after you setup the signal, and wake it up inside your signal function.

Comment: Absolutely not, that the normal way to wait some signal

Comment: `SIGCONT` is not "connected" but "continue", as in the process was stopped (after receiving "SIGSTP").

Comment: Yes, but it's the better way I found for just send "hey I send you a signal" without stop the process

Comment: I edited my comment about semaphores, instead of userland spin-lock.

Comment: Have you got an example of that, I don't know anything about semaphores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you set a global variable in a signal handler. Then that variable is used in main thread to check if something was received.

```
// global variable
static sig_atomic_t signal_received = 0;
void connected(int signum) {
   signal_received++;
}
void main_thread(void) {
   ...
   if (signal(SIGUSR1, connected) == SIG_ERR) {
       abort(); // handle error!
   }
   while(1) {
      // main loop with work
      if (signal_received > 0) {
          signal_received--;
          write(1, "\nenemy connected\n\n", 18);
          map = host_map();
          // do other stuff here
      }
      pause(); // let others run!
               // TODO: use sigsuspend as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328055/whats-the-problem-of-pause-at-all
   }
}
```

A better concurrently program would start a separate thread upon receiving a signal with `SIGEV_THREAD` or start a separate thread beforehand and call `sigwait` in that thread.