# Can't use system call write() correctly

Tags: c, linux

The assignment is

> Write a program in C/Posix (Linux environment) that synchronizes a parent process and his child process (using signals) that reads and write one by one numbers from `1` to `n` (given by the user) in the first position of a txt file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    int i;
    int fd = open("exercise.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0777);

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (!pid) {
        for (i = 1; i <= (n / 2); i++) {
            pause();
            char c[2];
            sprintf(c, "%d", i + 1);
            write(fd, c, sizeof(c));
            kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
        }
    }

    else {
        for (i = 1; i <= (n / 2); i++) {
            char c[2];
            sprintf(c, "%d", i);
            write(fd, c, sizeof(c));
            kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
            pause();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For each number I pass to my program I always find a txt file with just "1" written in it instead of 1234...n.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: both processes stop at pause until a signal is received.

Comment: Your int type is only 2 bytes?

Comment: no int is 4byte by default but I don't care because I want to convert it to a string

Comment: Where is your signal handler? I read [somewhere](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Signals.html) that the default action of SIGUSR1 is to terminate the process. That might explain the result you observed.

Comment: Off-topic: (1) You are writing a NUL character after each number, so the result would be "1\02\03\0..." rather than "123..." (2) Your program suffers from buffer overflow when n >= 20. In C, that is a serious offence.

Answer (score 0):

The *child* process will immediately [`pause`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pause.2.html) upon entering the first iteration of the loop, waiting to receive a signal.

In the first iteration of its loop, the *parent* process will write two bytes of data to the file, send the `SIGUSR1` signal to the *child* process, and then itself [`pause`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pause.2.html), waiting to receive a signal.

The default action when receiving `SIGUSR1` is to terminate the process.

> pause()  returns  only when a signal was caught and the signal-catching function returned.

Thus the *child* process never does anything but *possibly* wait for a signal and *certainly* terminate almost immediately.

The *parent* process remains paused, waiting for a signal.

---

Some notes:

[`signal(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for an overview of signals.

The instructions were, as far as I can tell, to `write` in one process, and `read` in the other. Your program attempts to write in both processes.

```
char c[2];
sprintf(c, "%d", i); /* or i + 1 */
```

`c` is only large enough to store strings of, at most, length `1` (optionally one character, plus the null-terminating byte, always). This risks [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior), as there will not be enough room in the buffer if the third argument to `sprintf` is outside the range [0, 9].

In the *child* process, `pid` will be `0` in `kill(pid, SIGUSR1);`. From [`kill(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html):

> If *pid* equals 0, then *sig* is sent to every process in the process group of the calling process.

Opening the file *before* forking, means the two processes share the same file description. Changing the file offset (by reading, writing, or seeking) in one process will change it in the other.

In any case, the instructions are to always write and read at the start of the file ([`lseek(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html)).

---

You need to catch the delivery of `SIGUSR1`, or the default action of process termination will occur.

Additionally, the pattern of `kill` and then `pause` is not sufficient to avoid a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) wherein a signal is delivered *before* the process pauses to wait for signals. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6328242/2505965) covers the problem, and a solution. The method detailed is to use [`sigprocmask(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html) to normally delay (block) the delivery of signals and then [`sigsupend(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigsuspend.2.html) to temporarily handle those signals.

Here is a cursory example, lacking error handling, wherein the *parent* process writes and the *child* process reads.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void pdie(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void handler(int sig)
{
    signal(sig, handler);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    int fd = open("exercise.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0777);

    if (-1 == fd)
        pdie("open");

    int n = atoi(argv[1]);

    if (n < 1)
        n = 10;

    sigset_t set, old;

    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, &old);
    signal(SIGUSR1, handler);

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (-1 == pid)
        pdie("fork");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char buf[32];

        if (pid) {
            /* parent writes */
            int len = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%d", i + 1);

            lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
            write(fd, buf, (size_t) len);

            kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
            sigsuspend(&old);
        } else {
            /* child reads */
            sigsuspend(&old);

            memset(buf, 0, sizeof buf);
            lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);

            ssize_t bytes = read(fd, buf, sizeof buf - 1);
            printf("Child read %zd bytes: %s\n", bytes, buf);
            kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
        }
    }

    close(fd);

    if (pid)
        waitpid(pid, NULL, WUNTRACED);
}
```