# Parent-child signal communication enters deadlock

Tags: c++, c, unix, signals

I have implemented two programs (parent.cpp, child.c) that are supposed to communicate via signals to work indefinitely in an alternating fashion. However, for some reason the programs enter a deadlock after a random amount of time and I can not figure out why (the signal to the parent seems to be dropped without executing the signal handler; thus, both wait for a signal from the other process).

The steps taken by the programs: First, the parent is initialized, spawns the child and waits for the child's initialization (cf. `LLVMFuzzerInitialize` in parent.cpp). Then, a loop is entered and in each iteration `LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput` is called. Here, (1) the parent writes data to the child's stdin, (2) wakes up the child via SIGUSR2, (3) the child processes the data and (4) wakes up the parent via SIGUSR1.

On Linux, `parent` usually halts after a few thousand iterations while `parent_main` runs indefinitely on most runs (although sometimes it halts after a few ten thousand iterations, too). On Mac, both programs halt after a few seconds.

Below is a minimum working sample consisting of the parent.cpp, the child.c and a Makefile:

```
// parent.cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

static volatile sig_atomic_t signal_received = 0;

static pid_t child_pid = -1;
static int fdin[2], fdout[2];

void handleSIGUSR1(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
    if (child_pid == info->si_pid)
        signal_received = 1;
}

void handleSIGCHLD(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void initPipes()
{
    if (pipe(fdin) < 0)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    if (pipe(fdout) < 0)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void initSignalHandler()
{
    struct sigaction act = {0};

    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART;

    {
        act.sa_sigaction = &handleSIGUSR1;
        sigaction(SIGUSR1, &act, NULL);
    }

    {
        act.sa_sigaction = &handleSIGCHLD;
        sigaction(SIGCHLD, &act, NULL);
    }
}

void waitForChild()
{
    sigset_t mask, oldmask;
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGUSR1);

    if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &oldmask) == -1)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    while (signal_received == 0)
    {
        sigsuspend(&oldmask);
    }
    signal_received = 0;
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, NULL) == -1)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerInitialize(int *argc, char ***argv)
{
    initPipes();
    initSignalHandler();

    child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid < 0)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    if (child_pid == 0)
    {
        if (dup2(fdin[0], STDIN_FILENO) < 0)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        if (dup2(fdout[1], STDOUT_FILENO) < 0)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        char file[] = "./child";
        char *const argv[] = {"child", NULL};
        char *env[] = {NULL};

        execve(file, argv, env);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Waiting until child is initialized
    waitForChild();

    return 0;
}

extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t *Data, size_t Size)
{
    static int iteration = 0;
    std::cout << "parent.iteration: " << iteration++ << std::endl;

    char buffer[1024];
    write(fdin[1], buffer, 1024);

    kill(child_pid, SIGUSR2);

    waitForChild();

    return 0;
}

#ifdef DEFINE_MAIN
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    LLVMFuzzerInitialize(&argc, &argv);
    for (;;)
    {
        uint8_t buffer[1];
        LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(buffer, 1);
    }
}
#endif
```

```
// child.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static volatile sig_atomic_t signal_received = 0;

void handleSIGUSR2(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
    signal_received = 1;
}

void waitForParent()
{
    sigset_t mask, oldmask;
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGUSR2);

    if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &oldmask) == -1) {
        perror("sigprocmask-block (child)");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (signal_received == 0)
    {
        sigsuspend(&oldmask);
    }
    signal_received = 0;
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigprocmask-unblock (child)");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    };
}

void readPackage()
{
    uint8_t buffer[1024];
    read(0, buffer, 1024);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sigaction act = {0};
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART;
    act.sa_sigaction = &handleSIGUSR2;
    sigaction(SIGUSR2, &act, NULL);

    // Notify parent about initialization
    kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);

    while (1)
    {
        static int iteration = 0;

        waitForParent();

        fprintf(stderr, "child.iteration: %d\n", iteration++);
        readPackage();

        kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
    }
}
```

```
all: child parent parent_main

child: child.c
    clang -fsanitize=address $< -o $@

parent: parent.cpp
    clang++ -fsanitize=fuzzer,address $< -o $@

parent_main: parent.cpp
    clang++ -DDEFINE_MAIN $< -o $@
```

**Edit:**

On Linux (archlinux 5.19.11, clang version: 14.0.6), I could not yet get `parent_main` into a deadlock state again, but I used `strace -f ./parent` (for brevity, I only show the last two iterations):

```
[pid 167430] write(1, "parent.iteration: 1698\n", 23) = 23
[pid 167430] write(4, "0\0\0\0 `\0\0`\204\10\334\376\177\0\0\20\205\10\334\376\177\0\0\352\213\216\200\337U\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
[pid 167430] kill(167431, SIGUSR2)      = 0
[pid 167431] <... rt_sigsuspend resumed>) = ? ERESTARTNOHAND (To be restarted if no handler)
[pid 167430] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [USR1],  <unfinished ...>
[pid 167431] --- SIGUSR2 {si_signo=SIGUSR2, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=167430, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 167430] <... rt_sigprocmask resumed>[], 8) = 0
[pid 167431] rt_sigreturn({mask=[USR2]} <unfinished ...>
[pid 167430] rt_sigsuspend([], 8 <unfinished ...>
[pid 167431] <... rt_sigreturn resumed>) = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
[pid 167431] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [USR2], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid 167431] write(2, "child.iteration: 1698\n", 22child.iteration: 1698
) = 22
[pid 167431] read(0, "0\0\0\0 `\0\0`\204\10\334\376\177\0\0\20\205\10\334\376\177\0\0\352\213\216\200\337U\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
[pid 167431] getppid()                  = 167430
[pid 167431] kill(167430, SIGUSR1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 167430] <... rt_sigsuspend resumed>) = ? ERESTARTNOHAND (To be restarted if no handler)
[pid 167431] <... kill resumed>)        = 0
[pid 167430] --- SIGUSR1 {si_signo=SIGUSR1, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=167431, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 167431] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [USR2],  <unfinished ...>
[pid 167430] rt_sigreturn({mask=[USR1]} <unfinished ...>
[pid 167431] <... rt_sigprocmask resumed>[], 8) = 0
[pid 167430] <... rt_sigreturn resumed>) = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
[pid 167431] rt_sigsuspend([], 8 <unfinished ...>
[pid 167430] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [USR1], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid 167430] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {tv_sec=1665498102, tv_nsec=952308734}) = 0
[pid 167430] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {tv_sec=1665498102, tv_nsec=952354900}) = 0


[pid 167430] write(1, "parent.iteration: 1699\n", 23) = 23
[pid 167430] write(4, "0\0\0\0 `\0\0`\204\10\334\376\177\0\0\20\205\10\334\376\177\0\0\352\213\216\200\337U\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
[pid 167430] kill(167431, SIGUSR2)      = 0
[pid 167431] <... rt_sigsuspend resumed>) = ? ERESTARTNOHAND (To be restarted if no handler)
[pid 167430] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [USR1],  <unfinished ...>
[pid 167431] --- SIGUSR2 {si_signo=SIGUSR2, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=167430, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 167430] <... rt_sigprocmask resumed>[], 8) = 0
[pid 167431] rt_sigreturn({mask=[USR2]} <unfinished ...>
[pid 167430] rt_sigsuspend([], 8 <unfinished ...>
[pid 167431] <... rt_sigreturn resumed>) = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
[pid 167431] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [USR2], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid 167431] write(2, "child.iteration: 1699\n", 22child.iteration: 1699
) = 22
[pid 167431] read(0, "0\0\0\0 `\0\0`\204\10\334\376\177\0\0\20\205\10\334\376\177\0\0\352\213\216\200\337U\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
[pid 167431] getppid()                  = 167430
[pid 167432] <... clock_nanosleep resumed>0x7ff1859f8de0) = 0
[pid 167431] kill(167430, SIGUSR1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 167430] <... rt_sigsuspend resumed>) = ? ERESTARTNOHAND (To be restarted if no handler)
[pid 167432] --- SIGUSR1 {si_signo=SIGUSR1, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=167431, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 167431] <... kill resumed>)        = 0
[pid 167430] rt_sigsuspend([], 8 <unfinished ...>
[pid 167431] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [USR2],  <unfinished ...>
[pid 167432] rt_sigreturn({mask=[]} <unfinished ...>
[pid 167431] <... rt_sigprocmask resumed>[], 8) = 0
[pid 167432] <... rt_sigreturn resumed>) = 0
[pid 167431] rt_sigsuspend([], 8 <unfinished ...>
```

It looks like that although the child calls `kill(1674310, SIGUSR1)`, the signal arrives in the libFuzzer-process (pid:167432)... I am not sure where to go from here?

Comment: When you say that one or both programs "halt", do you mean that they *terminate* or that stop emitting output without terminating?

Comment: @JohnBollinger The latter: They both wait for a signal of the other process

Comment: I don't think it's a likely issue, but I nevertheless do recommend checking the return values of *all* library functions that use them to notify of failures.  You check some of those, but by no means all.  I think the most likely outcome of adding such checks is that you confirm that all the function calls are succeeding, but without the checks, you don't know.

Comment: I built your programs on Linux with the GCC suite, version 8.5.0.  That required these minor adjustments: (i) removing the "fuzzer" option from `-fsanitize`; (ii) merging the `parent` and `parent_main` targets, because the former fails with a link error on account of not defining a `main()` function; and (iii) fixing the parent's `char *const argv[] = {"child", NULL};`, which is valid C, but not valid C++.  The result ran successfully for more than 5 million iterations before I stopped it manually.

Comment: On Linux, what does _strace_ tell you?  I cannot deadlock it there.  On OS X I avoid deadlock — the programs are apparently stuck in never-ending `sigsuspend` — if I remove the _si_pid_ check in the handler.  (Every so often _si_pid_ appears to be zero when accompanying the USR1 on the send — what do you see if you safely copy _info_ ?). In my experience OS X is POSIXy until it isn't, so this failure isn't quite as interesting to me.

Comment: @pilcrow I added the strace output to the question. It looks like the signal is delivered to the wrong process... I haven't noticed the missing si_pid yet and will look into it. What do you mean by "safely copy"?

Comment: @JohnBollinger As I understand it, the setup should be equivalent to the `parent_main` program. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to reproduce the deadlock for this program (but I am sure that it _rarely_ happens there, too). I will catch the remaining function calls' return values and see if I can get parent_main into a deadlock (while running `strace`).

Comment: @JonasMöller can we [talk about this in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248735/signal-handling-in-c-c)?